# I am trying to make a history for a text to speech program and the program is getting an error with the code I'm using

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Okay let me start that here is the code that in using:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SAPI
    SAPI = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
    SAPI.Speak(RichTextBox1.Text)
    My.Settings.History.Add(RichTextBox1.Text.ToString)
End Sub
```

Then I sarted the application.
But then I click Button1 I get this:

[image]

Without the code for the history it works just fine. Maybe there is a way better way to do it.
Please help.

Comment: Set a breakpoint to see what line its failing on...

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/dd7f738b27c19b0b6744041a63dadd8d.png

Comment: See answer I submitted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

That's because your saving your settings wrong. See example below...

Change and save Settings

```
 My.Settings.History = RichTextBox1.Text
 My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: I tried adding My.Settings.Save() but that didn't work, then I tried changing My.Settings.History.Add(RichTextBox1.Text.ToString) to My.Settings.History = RichTextBox1.Text then I get "Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection'." in the Error List.

Comment: In your settings, change that field to a string.

Comment: NullReferenceException "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."